# How can I link a custom Contact field to the Cases module in SuiteCRM 8.4.1 and display selected contacts in the Subpanel?

Tags: suitecrm

I'm currently working with SuiteCRM version 8.4.1, and I'm facing an issue related to custom fields and subpanels. Specifically, I have created a custom field called "Contact" that accepts contact details from the database.

My task is to establish a connection between this custom "Contact" field and the Contacts module, such that when I select a contact from the "Contact" field, it should automatically display in the Subpanel of the Cases module.

I've been researching this issue and trying various approaches, but I haven't been able to find a clear solution. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this integration and ensure that selected contacts are displayed in the Cases module's Subpanel when chosen from the custom "Contact" field?

Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I've been researching this issue and trying various approaches, but I haven't been able to find a clear solution. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this integration and ensure that selected contacts are displayed in the Cases module's Subpanel when chosen from the custom "Contact" field?